# Creating a dot density map with D3.js

Tags: javascript, dictionary, d3.js

Has anyone successfully created a [dot density map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_distribution_map) using D3.js? I'd love to see an example, but if anyone knows of an efficient "points in polygon" algorithm in JS, that would be useful as well. Here's [what I have so far](https://gist.github.com/cfarmer/5b32cd0b070f94349f4c), and here's [the block](http://bl.ocks.org/cfarmer/5b32cd0b070f94349f4c) to see it 'in action'.

Right now I have either Halton sequences or random points working. But there are problems: a) It is not very efficient (should probably use canvas), and b) I don't have the points clipped to the states, and c) Even if I did clip to states, the total *count* in each state would be wrong (based on bounds not geometry).

Any thoughts/ideas to improve any aspect of the above are greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's something along those lines that may be helpful in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/tomgp/8673139).

Comment: Thanks @LarsKotthoff. I had actually seen that one: Unfortunately, dot density in circles is relatively simple compared to arbitrarily complex polygons.

Comment: Interesting questions I wouldn't have thought that performance would be much of an issue, as you could effectively set your density to be a function of radius and number of point to achieve the same visual perception.  That is, fewer larger dots.  However, you may have other reasons or constraints.  As for part b) would  [projection.clipExtent](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#clipExtent) help.  c) I can't think of anything precise but imprecise calculate the area of the features bounding box and populate that at the density you want then use clipExtent?

Comment: Hi @user1614080, thanks for the ideas. I think clipExtent will only help to clip to the extent of the specified viewport, which is really just a bounding box, so not quite precise enough (i.e., doesn't clip to polygon boundaries). As for c), I think this is probably what I'll end up doing if I can find a viable alternative to clipExtent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andy Woodruff has created a canvas-based dot density map with d3 at

http://bl.ocks.org/awoodruff/94dc6fc7038eba690f43

While this may not be exactly what you are looking for (it's pixel-based and not vectorized / SVG, although implemented in d3), you may get some inspirations from it. You may even consider creating the proposed canvas-based solution off-screen for point-in-polygon checking, to determine the coordinates of points to set in your SVG representation.

Comment: This is great, thanks! As you said, not quite what I was looking for, but an excellent and useful approximation.